# Can't check user IDs in AD to see if they are active via PS

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to load in a list of users and want to run each user against AD to see if their account is still active in AD or not. When I run the below PS script, I get a CSV file that says every ID has been removed, but a manual check shows that's not correct.

```
# Import the CSV file
$csvPath = "File path\User IDs.csv"
$users = Import-Csv $csvPath

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

# Initialize the $userID variable outside of the foreach loop
$userID = $null

# Iterate over each user ID
foreach ($user in $users) {
    
    $userID = $user.ID

    try {

    # Check AD for account status
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $userID -Properties Enabled

    # Determine if the account is active
    $isActive = if ($adUser.Enabled -eq $true) { "Active" } else { "Inactive" }

    # Create a custom object with the ID and Active? properties
    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID = $userID
        "Active?" = $isActive
    }

    # Add the result to the array
    $results += $result

    } catch {

        Write-Host "$userID not found in Active Directory"

        # Create a custom object with the ID and Active? properties
        $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ID = $userID
            "Active?" = "Removed"
    }

        # Add the result to the array
        $results += $result

    }

}


# Export the results to a new CSV file
$resultsPath = "File path\Active IDs.csv"
$results | Export-Csv -Path $resultsPath -NoTypeInformation
```

I am still quite new to the world of programming, so I am trying to understand where I am going wrong. Thanks!

I tried the script without the try {} and catch {}, but then it would give me errors that 'userID' not found in expression: $userID is not defined then would give an InvalidArgument error for Get-ADUser, ArgumentException

Comment: can we assume your CSV has a column with name `ID` and the values of that column are the user's samAccountName or distinguishedName or GUID or SID ?

Comment: Is it valid to put statements between the `try` block and `catch` block?

Comment: The CSV file has no file headers, I made sure to remove them before running the script. The list contains samAccountNames

Comment: I'm not sure about the try and catch blocks. I tried to create this on my own, hit roadblocks and consulted ChatGPT, which created the above final script with the try and catch blocks added. I'm open to writing this differently if they aren't needed

Comment: If your file has no headers then `Import-Csv` is not the right cmdlet to import the file, because the file is not a Csv. Use `Get-Content` instead.

Comment: I tried it with Get-Content and even though the source file has a .csv extension, it still didn't work. Based on your last comment, I went into the CSV file and added a header for "ID" and re-ran the script. This time, it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated in comments:

> The CSV file has no file headers, I made sure to remove them before running the script. The list contains samAccountNames.

Then `Import-Csv` is not the correct cmdlet to import your file because your file is not a Csv, use `Get-Content` instead to read the file content. The final code, with some improvements would be:

```bash
# Path to the txt file with samAccountNames
$filePath = 'File path\User IDs.txt'
# Export path
$resultsPath = 'File path\Active IDs.csv'

Get-Content $filePath | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $adUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $_
        if ($adUser.Enabled) {
            $isActive = 'Active'
        }
        else {
            $isActive = 'Inactive'
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
        $isActive = 'Removed'
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ID        = $_
        'Active?' = $isActive
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $resultsPath -NoTypeInformation
```